# How to get Serialize Output Data?

Tags: php, arrays, database, serialization

I need Output in this format: `a:1:{s:11:"category_id";s:2:"1";}`

I tried below code

```
$a = array('category_id',1);

echo serialize($a);
```

Result: `a:2:{i:0;s:11:"category_id";i:1;i:41;}`

How to get above result? I also tried `json_encode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the array as

```
$a = array('category_id'=> "1 ");
```

As the serialised params are in the format `type:length:value`, you need to pass 1 as a string.

Also `s:2:"1"` won't be possible as 1 has a length of `1` not `2`. If you want a string of 2 length, maybe we can pass `<space>` to acheive that.